# Python Update values in list from dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to convert values in nested list from dict

```py
list1 =  [["a","b"],["c"],["a","d"]]

list2 =  [["a","b"],["c"],[""],["a","d"]]

dict_form = {"a":"app","b":"bold","c":"cafe","d":"dot"}
```

Expected output

```py
new_list = [["app","bold"],["cafe"],["app","dot"]]

result_1 = [["app","bold"],["cafe"],[""],["app","dot"]]
```

What I have tried:

```py
result = [[dict_form[i] for i in j] for j in new_list]
```

Comment: Why do you use `new_list` is your try ? This is the list you except ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another way would be to just use map:

```
list(map(lambda x: list(map(dict_form.get, x)), list1))
```

output:

```
[['app', 'bold'], ['cafe'], ['app', 'dot']]
```

slight variation:

```
[*map(lambda x: [*map(dict_form.get, x)], list1)]
```

As a follow up to @azro's timings, I generated a much larger input list1 with the same kind of structure..

using the current input from the OP, approx:

nested list comprehension  = `0.000000833 s`

map method = `0.000001440 s`

map method variation = `0.000001180 s`

with a MUCH larger but similar list, approx:

nested list comprehension  = `0.054890156 s`

map method = `0.050899744 s`

map method variation = `0.065859318 s`

So I guess the most efficient solution (from those provided) depends on the size of your actual list, seems the map method tends to perform the best as the lists get larger

Comment: Thanks. It worked. What if there empty list in between?

Comment: then it returns an empty [] in that position

Answer (score 4):

Use a 2-level list comprehension

```
result = [[dict_form[k] for k in sublist] for sublist in list1]
print(result) # [['app', 'bold'], ['cafe'], ['app', 'dot']]
```

---

`Timeit` on 20 loops of 200k iterations

```
# List comprehension : [[dict_form[k] for k in sublist] for sublist in list1]
python -m timeit -r 20 -n 200000 -s "list1 =  [['a','b'],['c'],['a','d']];dict_form = {'a':'app','b':'bold','c':'cafe','d':'dot'}" "[[dict_form[k] for k in sublist] for sublist in list1]"
200000 loops, best of 20: 1.74 usec per loop

# list/map : list(map(lambda x: list(map(dict_form.get, x)), list1))
python -m timeit -r 20 -n 200000 -s "list1 =  [['a','b'],['c'],['a','d']];dict_form = {'a':'app','b':'bold','c':'cafe','d':'dot'}" "list(map(lambda x: list(map(dict_form.get, x)), list1))"
200000 loops, best of 20: 3.2 usec per loop
```

So more performant on normal list length, and same on huge list (see Derek post)

Comment: Thanks. It worked.
What if there empty list in between?

Comment: @anthonymartial it'll keep it as empty

Comment: @anthonymartial The answer you accept is 2 times less performant, it seems more pythonic but that is not a case to use it efficiently

Comment: @DerekEden seems that is scales well, and it's just more readable that double list+map but ok ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use a nested list comprehension:

```
list1 =  [["a","b"],["c"],["a","d"]]
dict_form = {"a":"app","b":"bold","c":"cafe","d":"dot"}
new_list = [[dict_form[k] for k in ls] for ls in list1]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[['app', 'bold'], ['cafe'], ['app', 'dot']]
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. What if there empty list in between?